# compare multiple columns of pandas dataframe with one column of another dataframe having different length and index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have dataframe 
dd1:

```
     A   B   C  D    E  
  0  V  10   5  18  20       
  1  W   9  18  11  13      
  2  X   8   7  12   5      
  3  Y   7   9   7   8       
  4  Z   6   5   3  90
```

I want to add a column 'Result' in dd1 which should return zero if value in column 'E' is greater than values in dd1 columns A,B,C and D else return that value which is greater than dd1 column E

```
   A   B   C   D   E  Result
0  V  10   5  18  20       0
1  W   9  18  11  13      18
2  X   8   7  12   5      12
3  Y   7   9   7   8       9
4  Z   6   5   3  90       0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) columns selected by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or list of columns names, check if all `True`s per rows by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to new column:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:-1]
#for select by columns names
#df1 = df[['B','C','D']]
df['Result'] = np.where(df1.lt(df['E'], axis=0).all(axis=1), 0, df1.max(axis=1))
```

Another idea is compare by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) with max values per selected columns and then multiple by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
s = df.iloc[:, 1:-1].max(axis=1)
df['Result'] = s.gt(df['E']).mul(s)
print (df)
   A   B   C   D   E  Result
0  V  10   5  18  20       0
1  W   9  18  11  13      18
2  X   8   7  12   5      12
3  Y   7   9   7   8       9
4  Z   6   5   3  90       0
```

Comment: in real i have two dataframe in one dataframe there are 9 columns and i have to compare that all 9 columns with 2nd  dataframe which has only one column and return the value of greater value in 2nd dataframe in new column called result.

Comment: @vishwajeet - both DataFrames have same index values and same length?

Comment: Both having different index and length also @jezrael

Comment: @vishwajeet - If need something else like another DataFrame with different index and length, the vest is create new question, else if edited original question then answer not matched. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) value of each row (axis=1), and compare that to the `E` column. If this condition is True, we return 0, else we return the `max` value of that row:

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df.iloc[:, 1:].max(axis=1).eq(df['E']), # our condition
                        0,                                      # value if true
                        df.iloc[:, 1:].max(axis=1))             # value if false
```

---

```
print(df)
   A   B   C   D   E  Result
0  V  10   5  18  20       0
1  W   9  18  11  13      18
2  X   8   7  12   5      12
3  Y   7   9   7   8       9
4  Z   6   5   3  90       0
```

**Explanation**
[`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) works as followed:

```
np.where(condition, value if true, value if false)
```